# Spark Explode a row containing multiple metrics using Map

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**I am using Spark with Java and have a dataframe like this:**

```
id | sent  | delivered | opened
--------------------------------
1  | 5     | 3         | 2
2  | 11    | 9         | 4
```

**I want to get something like:**

```
id  | metric_name | metric_value
--------------------------------
1   | sent        |  5
1   | delivered   |  3
1   | opened      |  2
2   | sent        |  11
2   | delivered   |  9
2   | opened      |  4
```

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick:

```
df = df.selectExpr(
  "id",
  "stack(3, 'sent', sent, 'delivered', delivered, 'opened', opened) as (metric_name, metric_value)"
)
```

Final output:

```
+---+-----------+------------+
|id |metric_name|metric_value|
+---+-----------+------------+
|1  |sent       |5           |
|1  |delivered  |3           |
|1  |opened     |2           |
|2  |sent       |11          |
|2  |delivered  |9           |
|2  |opened     |4           |
+---+-----------+------------+
```

Good luck!

Comment: Np, please mark the answer as solved for future reference

Answer (score 0):

Create a struct columns combining column names and values of the columns you want to melt.
Explode using inline

```
 df1 =df.withColumn('tab',F.array(*[F.struct(F.lit(x).alias('metric_name'), F.col(x).alias('metric_value ')) for x in df.columns if x != 'id'])).selectExpr('id','inline(tab)')
```

df1.show(truncate=False)

```
+---+-----------+-------------+
|id |metric_name|metric_value |
+---+-----------+-------------+
|1  |sent       |5            |
|1  |delivered  |3            |
|1  |opened     |2            |
|2  |sent       |11           |
|2  |delivered  |9            |
|2  |opened     |4            |
+---+-----------+-------------+
```